# Excel scaling line thickness

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a strange question and I hope someone can help me to figure it out.

I've a data set and want to have lines of various thickness that relates to a percentage of each value.

For example, I have different sources and want the line that represent line 1 with 65% to be the thickest and line 2 could be smaller and have 20% and line 3 the thinnest with the last 15%. Is there a way to have the line thickness auto adjust to represent the percentages?

Comment: is this just a matter or not knowing how to assign line thickness to a series in a line or scatter plot?

Answer (score 2):

*It's possible to set the thickness of Line.*

**Option 1:**

*Line in Line graph only, using Cell values.*

**But always remember this procedure considers value as `Numbers, in General format` never as `Percentage format`.**

*To achieve the goal you need VBA (Macro).*

[image]

**How it Works:**

- Enter required data in Sheet and assign *NAME* 
  to the Range, using **Formula** then **Define 
  Name** & finish with **ok**.

[image]

- Right click **Sheet TAB** & from Poped up Menu 
  select **View Code**.
- Excel will open VB editor.
- **Copy** & **Paste** this code as **Standard 
  Module**.

  ```
  Sub SetWidth()
   Dim Srs As Series
   Dim myWidth As Range
   Dim Rn As Range
   Dim j As Long

   Set myWidth = Range("Thickness")

   j = 1

   With ActiveSheet
      For Each Rn In myWidth
          If j > ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count Then Exit Sub
          ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(j).Format.Line.Weight = Rn
          j = j + 1
      Next Rn
    End With
   End Sub
  ```
- Select the Graph & **RUN** the Macro.

*You find the new width to the Lines in the 
 Graph.*

**Note,** `Thickness` is the Name given to Range `A1:C2`, which is editable also.

**Option 2:**

*Change the Height/Thickness of a Line object.*

Use this Macro as Standard Module.

```
Sub LineWidth()

     With ActiveSheet.Shapes("Straight Connector 2")
        .Visible = True
        .Width = Range("A1").Value
        .Height = Range("A2").Value
    End With

End Sub
```

**Note,** `Straight Connector 2` is Line 
  object.